# Stack is in UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS state and can not be updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloud9

I'm trying to deploy a Lambda function inside Cloud9, but it is failing.

When I right-click on the function and click Deploy, I get `Application deployment failed`, and then a popup:

```
AWS CloudFormation Deployment Errors
Stack:arn:aws:cloudformation:* is in UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS state and cannot be updated.
```

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this issue deploying using the serverless framework.

The solution ended up just being *waiting*, but it took **almost a full hour** for the state to clear itself. There were no new events showing up. I just had to wait a long, long time.

Comment: Still see this in early '24. Go grab a cup of coffee and set a 60m timer. You'll be stuck for a while.

Comment: Same. took well over an hour for me.

Comment: I got hit by this. In my case, it was a `AWS::Lambda::Version` that failed to delete. In the events, it shows as trying to start the deletion, but the resource itself never transitioned to deletion in progress. It just stalled out, and then the stack was left locked.

Answer (score 2):

If your deployment is building another Stack in CloudFormation, you may want to check for existing ones with the same name that may be conflicting with the Stack created by your deployment.

Go to CloudFormation, find the conflicting Stack, delete all resources (in that stack), and finally delete the stack.

Deploy again and it should work this time.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudformation throws this error when part, or a sub-stack, of the CloudFormation template, could not be updated or rolled back properly. This can happen if something modified the portion in question outside of what the template says. Here is an excerpt from the docs regarding this issue:

> A nested stack might fail to roll back because of changes that were made outside of AWS CloudFormation when the stack template doesn't accurately reflect the state of the stack. A nested stack might also fail if an Auto Scaling group in a nested stack had an insufficient resource signal timeout period when the group was created or updated.

Please read [Troubleshooting AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-errors-nested-stacks-are-stuck) to find more information about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for 5 minutes, and then trying the deployment again worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at cloudformation to understand what is failing. It seems stuck in IN_PROGRESS state probably due to retries but it will eventually complete as a failure after several failed attempts.